# flex-wrap is not working, even with min-width applied

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The problem is, when I decrease the browser window containers one after one should jump to next line and at the minimum browser window width there should be one column contains 3 containers one by one, but this is not happening. Instead of this, containers just getting smaller and staying in one line. I tried to use min-width (it's even in code, which I've pasted here :p)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #2c3e50;
  font-family: strait, sans-serif;
}

#box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  min-width: 70vw;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container {
  min-width: 20vw;
  height: 50vh;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  border: 2px solid darkgray;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: slide-animation 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes slide-animation {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-top: 300px;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div class="container"></div>
  <div class="container"></div>
  <div class="container"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `vw` units, the size of your flex items will always be a percentage of the viewport size. Without any content in the items, they can just keep shrinking to zero. That's a problem when wanting items with standard percentage or viewport percentage lengths to wrap.

Use a fixed unit.

Instead of this:

```
min-width: 20vw
```

Try this:

```
min-width: 12em
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #2c3e50;
  font-family: strait, sans-serif;
}

#box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  min-width: 70vw;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container {
  min-width: 12em;
  height: 50vh;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  border: 2px solid darkgray;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: slide-animation 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes slide-animation {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-top: 300px;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div class="container"></div>
  <div class="container"></div>
  <div class="container"></div>
</div>
```